# Why the current year in the date saved as 3912?

Tags: android, date, calendar

to get the current date and time

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

to create current date object

```
Date toDate;
     toDate.setYear(mYear);
     toDate.setMonth(mMonth);
     toDate.setDate(mDay);



Date endDate = toDate;
```

when printing endDate object I got

```
Mon Jan 01 13:11:00 GMT+03:00 3912
```

why ?

Comment: Is your system time set to the correct year?

Comment: y2.012K bug is causing issues

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From `Date.setYear(int)` description: *Sets the gregorian calendar year since 1900 for this Date object*. Thus, `1900 + 2012 = 3912`.

But `calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)` returns exact year number `2012`. So this inconsistency of API causes your issue. But anyway `Date.setYear(int)` is deprecated, thus, it is better to use `Calendar` object for date calculations.

Comment: @AdhamEnaya You may subtract `1900` from year number: `toDate.setYear(mYear - 1900)`. But I better suggest to use `Calendar` object for date calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use **Calendar**

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,myear);
```

*(i.e)*

```
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2016);
```